# Can not update data with ajax on codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I tried to update the data with ajax on php but it went wrong while ajax information has been successful but the data is not updated, I think the script is correct but do not want to update the data, what is wrong with my script ??

```
<input type="hidden"  id="select_id" name="select_id" value="<?php echo $read_inbox['id_data']; ?>" />

$('[id^=delete_read_inbox]').click(function() {         
    if (confirm('You are sure to delete this message?')) {
        var id = $("#select_id").val();
        var url = base_url+'message/delete_inbox_read';    
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'select_id='+id,
            success: function(response) { 
                console.log('success');                 
            },
            error: function (request, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        });
    } else {

    }       
 });
```

Controllers

```
function delete_inbox_read() {   
    $this->Message->delete_ReadInbox(); 
    redirect('user/message/inbox'); 
}
```

Models

```
function delete_ReadInbox() {   
    $update = $this->input->post('select_id');
    $data = array(
                'delete_pa_inbox' => 0
                );            
    $this->db->where('id_Message', $update);
    $this->db->update('tb_message', $data);               
}
```

Comment: Try with change to `$('[id^="delete_read_inbox"]').click(function() {` [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to POST '`id`' from js and fetching '`select_id`' on PHP side, hence its not working, change to:

```
...
var id = $("#select_id").val();
var url = base_url+'message/delete_inbox_read';    
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'id' : id },
    success: function(response) { 
        console.log('success');                 
    },
....
```

Controller:

```
function delete_inbox_read() {   
    //get the POST data
    $select_id = $this->input->post('id'); //id not select_id
    $this->Message->delete_ReadInbox($select_id); 
    //redirect('user/message/inbox'); //remove redirect
    echo "done";
}
```

Model:

```
function delete_ReadInbox($select_id) { 
    $data = array(
                'delete_pa_inbox' => 0
                );            
    $this->db->where('id_Message', $select_id);
    $this->db->update('tb_message', $data);               
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Sorry it was a mistake when making a question, I've tried to follow your answer but the results are still the same can not update

Comment: try to remove ` redirect('user/message/inbox'); ` from controller and redirect using javascript.